# Wordpress 404 error custom redirect .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I want to add some custom redirects on the same domain as a Wordpress installation. I want something like this:

```
domain.com/get/card/123456
```

to go to:

```
domain.com/account/client/redirectNewCard.php?id=123456
```

The same principle I want to happen to 2 other redirects, "client/validate/email/" en "enterprise/validate/email/". But none of them works.

Wordpress is saying a 404 page with "Page not found", but visiting "my domain.com/account/client/redirectNewCard.php?id=123456" DOES work and shows up what's supposed to show up.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^get/card/([0-9]+)$ /account/client/redirectNewCard.php?id=$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^client/validate/email/([0-9]+)$ /client/accountinstellingen.php?code=$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^enterprise/validate/email/([0-9]+)$ /enterprise/instellingen.php?code=$1 [R]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I already tried putting the redirect BEFORE and also AFTER the Wordpress redirects, but none of these approaches help. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^get/card/([0-9]+)$ /account/client/redirectNewCard.php?id=$1 [R]
> RewriteRule ^client/validate/email/([0-9]+)$ /client/accountinstellingen.php?code=$1 [R]
> RewriteRule ^enterprise/validate/email/([0-9]+)$ /enterprise/instellingen.php?code=$1 [R]
> ```

You need to include the `L` (`last`) flag on each of these directives. ie. `[R,L]`.

Without the `L` flag, processing will continue and is likely getting rewritten by the WordPress front-controller. You need processing to stop and redirect immediately.

Comment: Hero! Thanks a lot!!